# How to know if user tap on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

When i tap on button app launches a `smaller view`, i need to close it if user taps any where on the screen except that opened view.

I tried to add `TouchListener` to my parent layout, but its not detecting the click or touch event on the parent layout.

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            >

            <!-- VIEWS -->

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in my activity i have written following code, but this is not working.

```
activity_profile.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                when (event?.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        layoutContextual.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }

                return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

call setOnClickListener on  CoordinatorLayout id of the parent layout

```
activity_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // put your code here


        }
    });
```

Or

You can use the onTouchEvent()

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // put your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs are the things you are trying to implement.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

You can use custom view with or without title so it should match your expectations.